# How to write onDismissListener to AlertDialog builder?

Tags: android

Please see the code below.

```
final CharSequence[] cs = DeviceList.toArray(new CharSequence[DeviceList.size()]);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setTitle("Pick the Item");

    builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //do something
        }

    });

    builder.show();
```

Some one please help me to implement a builder onDismissListener event in this code?

Comment: implement `onDismiss()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
```

So, the complete code will be something like:

```
final CharSequence[] cs = DeviceList.toArray(new CharSequence[DeviceList.size()]);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setTitle("Pick the Item");

    builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //do something
        }

    });
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });

    builder.show();
```